# Chart.js canvas in Angular 6 is showing previous chart on mouse hover over the canvas

Tags: angularjs, typescript, chart.js, angular6, chart.js2

I am trying to show multiple types of charts by giving user the option to select the type of chart he/she is interested in viewing.

User can select the type of chart from the following HTML radio group code.

```html
<form>
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="bar" name="optradio" (change)="onchange()"  [(ngModel)]="chartType" checked>Bar Graph
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="pie" name="optradio" (change)="onchange()" [(ngModel)]="chartType">Pie Chart
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" value="line" name="optradio" (change)="onchange()" [(ngModel)]="chartType">Line Graph
 </label>
</form>
```

The changes are reflected in the "**chartType**" variable as when I am printing the value in my typescript file, it is showing the exact value as mentioned as **value** in input tag.

---

Even the charts are also changing as per requirements and I am getting the charts based on the user input.

**But when I hover the mouse over the chart, it is flickering and showing the other charts also mostly the previously clicked charts.**

---

Following is my Typescript file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from '../../Services/logger.service';
import { HttpService } from '../../Services/http.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private logger: LoggerService, private httpService: HttpService,private formsModule:FormsModule) { }
  private arr: Number[];
  private chartShow:boolean = false;
  private chartType = "bar";
  private chart = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPeopleCount();
  }

  getPeopleCount() {
    this.httpService.getPeopleCount().subscribe(res => {
      this.arr = res;
      this.chartShow = true;
      this.displayChart();
    });
  }
  onchange(){
    console.log(this.chartType);
    this.getPeopleCount();
  }
  displayChart(){
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: this.chartType,
      data: {
        labels: ["Very Poor", "Poor", "Average", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Number of Feedbacks',
          data: this.arr,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

---

**Note**: I have tried calling destroy method of the chart object as mentioned in various other answers, but it doesn't work here **as my chart object is an array** and I am **using Angular 6.**
I have used this approach as I knew this one only.
If there is any other approach then please mention that also.

Thanks in advance and please help me with the best possible way, mentioning what I did wrong and what I should do in order to make it correct.

Comment: Ive run into the same problem as you.  Just vanilla javascript.  It appears the data persists and the hover events continue to trigger even once new data is placed in the chart object.