# Angular 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file and accessing angular app outside localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I am getting **"'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."** when I am trying to run **ng serve --host 0.0.0.0** form my command prompt.

But as I run it via **node.js command prompt**, my issue resolve and I was able to run **ng serve --host 0.0.0.0**

Another thing,

It also ran when I prefix it with **npm run** to ng serve (as mentioned in a github issue), I was able to bring the services up. But then I was facing issue if I add --host 0.0.0.0 to npm run ng serve as it was throwing the following error.

```
D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback>npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

> feedback@0.0.0 ng D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback
> ng "serve" "0.0.0.0"

Project '0.0.0.0' could not be found in workspace.
Error: Project '0.0.0.0' could not be found in workspace.
at Workspace.getProject (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\node_modu
les\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:92:19)
at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedb
ack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:96:41)
at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap
[as project] 
(D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\node_modules\@angular\cl
i\models\architect-command.js:70:55)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\no
de_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\node_
modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feed
back\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
at TapSubscriber._next (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\node_modul
es\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\
node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\
node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback\node_mod
ules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! feedback@0.0.0 ng: `ng "serve" "0.0.0.0"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the feedback@0.0.0 ng script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\debjyoti.pandit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\201810-09
T09_24_36_064Z-debug.log
```

---

Since, I have to access the webapp outside localhost, that's why I am adding --host 0.0.0.0

Is there any better way to do, so that I can access from any system within my company network.
Please help me with a proper solution.

Can anyone tell me the reason why? What is happening which I am unable to get.?

Comment: find your IP using **ipconfig** and use it instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: Try ng serve --host <your IP> not 0.0.0.0

Comment: I have tried Using IP and direct ng serve -- host <IP> but it didn't worked. Please read the question properly. 

Answer (score 1):

Try running as

```
D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback>npm run ng serve -- --host 0.0.0.0
```

This will pass host argument to the command mentioned in `ng serve` and not `npm run` as such

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly. I clearly mentioned it is not working.

Comment: @DebjyotiPandit my suggestion is add -- twice 

D:\NewAngular\NewAngular\Angular\Feedback>npm run ng serve -- --host 0.0.0.0

Comment: It worked when I removed the space between -- and host.

Comment: When you add -- it will pass the subsequent arguments to the script mentioned inside your npm script(ng serve in this case)                                              
Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Comment: If you are familiar, help me in this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703847/chart-js-canvas-in-angular-6-is-showing-previous-chart-on-mouse-hover-over-the-c

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running your terminal with root/administrative privileges.